# iOS _OBJC_CLASS errors after adding a library to project

Tags: ios, xcode, payumoney

I am trying to add PayU money sdk to my project. And after adding `libiOSCustomBrowser.a` file it gives errors:

```
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Jenaveve/myApp/Utilities/PayUSdk'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKUserContentController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libiOSCustomBrowser.a(PUCBWebVC.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKWebView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libiOSCustomBrowser.a(PUCBMagicRetry.o)
      objc-class-ref in libiOSCustomBrowser.a(PUCBBaseConnection.o)
      objc-class-ref in libiOSCustomBrowser.a(PUCBWebVC.o)
      objc-class-ref in libiOSCustomBrowser.a(CBWKConnection.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKWebViewConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libiOSCustomBrowser.a(PUCBWebVC.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In build phases, in Link Binary with Libraries, this reference exists. What is wrong?

Comment: i think you have to set "other linker flags" to "-ObjC"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that library cannot support for x86_64 architecture.
Remove x86_64 architecture in

'Build Settings -> Valid architecture'

and rebuild.